# FullCalendar change border color not changing

Tags: css, fullcalendar

Hi I have this current CSS for fullCalendar (v 1.6.4):

```
.full-calendar .fc-content .fc-event-container .fc-event {
    background: #ef6262!important;
    border-color: #eb3d3d!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

When I add a new Class to an event (based on some programming calculations) I do this:

```
event.className = 'paused-event';
calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```

My `paused-event` CSS is this:

```
.paused-event,
.paused-event div,
.paused-event span {
    background: #71CCBF;
    border-color: #65B7AB;
}
```

The background color changes correctly, the border stays the same as the default CSS.

**Expectancy:**

The event color AND border should change when the `paused-event` class is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!important`s are overriding the latest class properties. You could try to add `!important` to `.paused-event` properties as well, but the best would be to avoid any `!important`s and simply override by impacting with a deeper selector (although it's weird the background does change considering the important):

`.class1` vs `div.class1.class2` (deeper one)

Anyways, if you simply need to solve that and fast you can try:

```
.paused-event,
.paused-event div,
.paused-event span {
    background: #71CCBF;
    border-color: #65B7AB !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope... The `!important` gives the same result.

Comment: Removing the "!important" from the original CSS made the trick. Tks